# php mysql + 3 dynamic droplist box

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

i am creating three dynamic drop list that the second is based on the selection of the first and the third is based on the selection of the second  using php and mysql to retrieve data and javascript

but  this is not happening   how to solve the problem because what ever i select  in the first list  everything is displayed in the second  and the third .

in each table i have the id of the drop list before the selected done as a foreign key

can anyone help me ????

## code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Register Page</title>
    <link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="style/imagesGallery.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    function reload(form)
    {
    var val=form.governorate.options[form.governorate.options.selectedIndex].value; 
    self.location='register.php?governorate=' + val ;
    }

    function reload3(form)
    {
    var val=form.governorate.options[form.governorate.options.selectedIndex].value; 
    var val2=form.district.options[form.district.options.selectedIndex].value; 

    self.location='register.php?governorate=' + val + '&district=' + val2 ;
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

    $governorate = "";
    $district = "";

    //$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT category,cat_id FROM category order by category"); 
    $quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT governorate_name,governorate_id FROM governorate order by governorate_name"); 


    //$cat=$_GET['cat']; 
    $governorate=$_GET['governorate'];
    var_dump($governorate);
    if(isset($governorate) and strlen($governorate) > 0)
    {
    $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT district_name,district_id FROM districts where governorate_id=$governorate order by district_name"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT district_name,district_id FROM districts order by district_name"); 
    } 

    $district=$_GET['district'];
    if(isset($district) and strlen($district) > 0){
    $quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT village_name FROM village where district_id=$district order by village_name"); 
    }
else
{
$quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT village_name FROM village order by village_name"); 
} 

    echo "<select name='governorate' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
    while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) 
{ 
    if($noticia2['governorate_id']==@$governorate)
{
echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[governorate_id]'>$noticia2[governorate_name]</option>"."<BR>";
}
    else
 {
  echo  "<option value='$noticia2[governorate_id]'>$noticia2[governorate_name]</option>";
  }
}
    echo "</select>";

    echo "<select name='district' onchange=\"reload3(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
    while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer))
 { 
    if($noticia['district_id']==@$district)
{
echo "<option selected value='$noticia[district_id]'>$noticia[district_name]</option>"."<BR>";
}
    else
  {
  echo  "<option value='$noticia[district_id]'>$noticia[district_name]</option>";
  }
}
    echo "</select>";   

    echo "<select name='village' ><option value=''>Select one</option>";
    while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer3)) 
{ 
    echo  "<option value='$noticia[village_name]'>$noticia[village_name]</option>";
}
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Comment: That code made me cry.

Comment: why is that ?? can you help me ??? or not

Comment: simple technique is that `onchange` of 1st selectbox fectch records associated with the `id` or `value` for the second and same approach for the third selectbox

Comment: @ dianuj how to use onchange here sorry but i am new to php and web development  can you help me ??

Comment: do you have any idea of `ajax`

Comment: You've asked this question three times today.

Comment: here is best solution follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872213/second-select-box-populate-from-first-selectbox-in-jquery

Comment: @ Kacey i asked this question many times because no one had given me the right answer or at least had help me

Comment: @ dianuj  no i do not have any idea  but i want to learn that is why i am asking so many questions

Comment: Try to isolate your bug (find minimal portion of code that fails), that way it will be easier to see the problem. E.g. instead of asking yourself(and others) why 3 dropboxes don't work, make some testing on smaller parts separately. Maybe some queries return wrong values? Or some conditions are not working? or html rendered incorrectly? This shuold lead you to some solution.

Answer (score 0):

I run the code you did and it works for me. The only change I made was creating the form element. I have to create a table to make it functional. 
I did not go throughout village. I stopped when I got districts working.

Here is the code I changed:

```
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root') or die('could not connect');
mysql_select_db('financial_system_local',$db);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Register Page</title>
    <link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="style/imagesGallery.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    function reload(form)
    {
    var val=form.governorate.options[form.governorate.options.selectedIndex].value; 
    self.location='register.php?governorate=' + val ;
    }

    function reload3(form)
    {
    var val=form.governorate.options[form.governorate.options.selectedIndex].value; 
    var val2=form.district.options[form.district.options.selectedIndex].value; 

    self.location='register.php?governorate=' + val + '&district=' + val2 ;
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
<form>
    <?php

    $governorate = "";
    $district = "";

    //$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT category,cat_id FROM category order by category"); 
    $quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT governorate_name,governorate_id FROM governorate order by governorate_name",$db);
    echo mysql_error($db); 


    //$cat=$_GET['cat']; 
    $governorate=$_GET['governorate'];
    var_dump($governorate);
    if(isset($governorate) and strlen($governorate) > 0)
    {
    $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT district_name,district_id FROM districts where governorate_id=$governorate order by district_name",$db); 
    }
    else
    {
        $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT district_name,district_id FROM districts order by district_name",$db); 
    } 

    $district=$_GET['district'];
    if(isset($district) and strlen($district) > 0){
    $quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT village_name FROM village where district_id=$district order by village_name"); 
    }
else
{
$quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT village_name FROM village order by village_name"); 
} 

    echo "<select name='governorate' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
    while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) 
{ 
    if($noticia2['governorate_id']==@$governorate)
{
echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[governorate_id]'>$noticia2[governorate_name]</option>"."<BR>";
}
    else
 {
  echo  "<option value='$noticia2[governorate_id]'>$noticia2[governorate_name]</option>";
  }
}
    echo "</select>";

    echo "<select name='district' onchange=\"reload3(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
    while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer))
 { 
    if($noticia['district_id']==@$district)
{
echo "<option selected value='$noticia[district_id]'>$noticia[district_name]</option>"."<BR>";
}
    else
  {
  echo  "<option value='$noticia[district_id]'>$noticia[district_name]</option>";
  }
}
    echo "</select>";   

    echo "<select name='village' ><option value=''>Select one</option>";
    while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer3)) 
{ 
    echo  "<option value='$noticia[village_name]'>$noticia[village_name]</option>";
}
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
    </form>
```